# Extjs 4.2 Paging toolbar with combbox item

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2

Why this is not working , is not doing anything , it just shows me the combobox with store ..but my functions dosent work ..:(

```
 Ext.define('aw.grid.PagingToolbar', {
extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
alias: 'widget.custompaging',
displayInfo: true,
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: ['5', '10', '15', '20'],
        width: 50,
        queryMode: 'local',
        allowBlank: false,
        editable: false,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        maskRe: /[0-9]/,
        listeners: {
            init: function (paging) {
                debugger;
                var me = this;
                paging.on('afterrender', me.onInitView, me);
            },
            onInitView: function (paging) {
                var me = this;
                me.setValue(paging.store.pageSize);
                for (var i = 0; i < paging.items.length; i++) {
                    if (paging.items.items[i].xtype == 'tbfill') {
                        paging.remove(paging.items.items[i]);
                        paging.add(i, me);
                    }
                }
                me.on('select', me.onPageSizeChanged, paging);
                me.on('specialkey', function (combo, e) {
                    if (13 === e.getKey()) {
                        me.onPageSizeChanged.call(paging, me);
                    }
                });
            },
            onPageSizeChanged: function (combo) {
                var me = this;
                me.store.pageSize = parseInt(combo.getRawValue(), 10);
                me.doRefresh();
            }
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'x - Rows selected'
    }
]
});
```

This is used on other page but i ddont know why my functions are not working not even debugger..:((

Comment: You should show where this paging toolbar class is being used on a grid. Just defining the class doesn't mean that it's actually wired up to be used by anything.

Comment: Its a little complicated :) in my grid i`m using as dockedItems xtype: 'custompaging' and dock:'bottom' ..but the rest of the code is very long..:-<

Comment: You need to set pageSize: 1 to enable the paging in the combobox, that might fix your issue but there is a lot of code around the listener that might be negating your efforts and the full code is not listed. 2. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438677/extjs-4-2-combobox-paging-issues-with-ajax-remote-query , this is an old post of mine when I was learning how to use AJAX, combobox and paging toolbar, code works. 3. Is all this paging code in the listener really required?

Comment: its not required the thing is that , i need somehow when pagingtoolbar is created that my combobox should take pageSize from  the Store that is in Grid..:-? its a little complicated i dont know how to explain ..